# How do you configure a react app to use typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to learn Typescript.

I have followed [these instructions](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) and added typescript to my new app (just created a few minutes ago).

I have also followed [these instructions](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/732) and replaced my empty (top-level) config file with:

```
{
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "jsx": "preserve"
        }
    }
}
```

There is still an error that says:

> tsconfig.json(2,1): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

Does anyone know what it means or how to solve it?

Comment: The example you've shown isn't valid JSON.

Comment: seems like too much curly braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [first instructions](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) should work fine. Make sure you don't have an old version of **create-react-app** globaly installed.

You can remove it with :

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And than create you project again with :

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```